# Client-size manipulation of a Dynamics CRM Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am trying to create some javascript to add to a form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

I have the following script which I have assigned to the forms `onLoad` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#CheckBox1').is(':checked')) {

        $('<div id="div2">Some Data Here</div>').insertAfter("#Div1");

        $('#divHeader').height('+=25px');

        var newtop = $('#divMain').position().top + 25;
        $('#divMain').css('top', newtop + 'px');
    }

});
```

The following is a stripped down version of the forms HTML

```
<div id="divHeader">
    <div id="Div1"></div>
</div>

<div id="divMain"></div>
```

When the form loads, what should happen is this:

```
<div id="divHeader">
    <div id="Div1"></div>
    <div id="Div2">Some Data Here</div>
</div>

<div id="divMain"></div>
```

That does happen.  However, the problem is that the `divHeader` and `divMain` do not resize, so the newly added `Div2` can't be seen unless the user scrolls down within the `divHeader`.

If I add an alert:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#CheckBox1').is(':checked')) {

        alert("Random alert");

        $('<div id="div2">Some Data Here</div>').insertAfter("#Div1");

        $('#divHeader').height('+=25px');

        var newtop = $('#divMain').position().top + 25;
        $('#divMain').css('top', newtop + 'px');
    }

});
```

The whole thing works perfectly.  How do I get this to work without the alert?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

`setTimeout` also works instead of using an `alert`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('#CheckBox1').is(':checked')) {

            $('<div id="div2">Some Data Here</div>').insertAfter("#Div1");

            $('#divHeader').height('+=25px');

            var newtop = $('#divMain').position().top + 25;
            $('#divMain').css('top', newtop + 'px');

        }
    }, 5000);

});
```

So it seems `$(document).ready` doesn't seem to do it's job properly.  In both cases `alert` or `setTimeout`, the form gets extra time to finish loading before the div tags are resized.

Comment: Instead of an alert could you [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) `divHeader`?

Comment: @DaveClark, Just tried focus on divHeader within the beginning of the if statement and just before the end of the if statement. Both times, it made no difference. The script doesn't resize the divHeader. I put the alert back in, and the divHeader resizes perfectly.

Comment: Is `newtop` value same in both cases?

Comment: Are you actually manipulating the DOM of a CRM-form (i.e. is your _divHeader_ corresponding to the header of the CRM-form), or is this a div inside a custom web resource you have added?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, no, newtop only applies to divMain.

Comment: @HenrikH, I am manipulating the DOM of the actual CRM-form.  Yes, divHeader corresponds to the header of the CRM-form.

Comment: @oshirowanen, can you try a `$( window ).on( "load", handler )` instead of document `ready` handler?

Comment: @oshirowanen, it is not recommended to do DOM manipulations in CRM. See my answer below for an alternative solution which uses the APIs supported by Microsoft (and thus is guaranteed to not break without warning when Microsoft makes future updates to CRM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely unsupported to do DOM manipulations in Dynamics CRM. See [Do Not Access the DOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developers-guide/hh771584(v=crm.5)#do-not-access-the-dom).

You will instead need to use supported methods of manipulating the form (i.e. [`Xrm.Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developers-guide/gg328474(v=crm.5))). While it is not possible to dynamically add/remove content on a CRM-form, you can show and hide elements. As I understand it, you are trying to show some content if a boolean field (presented as a checkbox) on the form is true.

This can be done by adding the control that you want to show/hide to your form (that control can either be one of the standard CRM-fields or a custom web resource, depending on your requirements). You would then write a bit of JavaScript to show/hide the control in question when your boolean attribute changes its value:

```js
function onload() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("booleanField").addOnChange(showMoreStuffInHeader);
    showMoreStuffInHeader();
}

function showMoreStuffInHeader() {
    var visible = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("booleanField").getValue();
    Xrm.Page.getControl("someDataHereControl").setVisible(visible);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery Plugin [Wait until element exists](https://gist.github.com/PizzaBrandon/5709010) Pluging will wait for element to appear in DOM and then fire given handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#CheckBox1').waitUntilExists(function () { //  OR $('#Div1').waitUntilExists(function ()
        if ($('#CheckBox1').is(':checked')) {

            $('<div id="div2">Some Data Here</div>').insertAfter("#Div1");

            $('#divHeader').height('+=25px');

            var newtop = $('#divMain').position().top + 25;
            $('#divMain').css('top', newtop + 'px');

        }
    });

});
```